# Laravel - how should I store data when I have form with many fields

Tags: php, laravel

Im wondering how should I store data when my form got too many fields, In my case I have 33 inputs and I had to create 4 models and migrations for different type of data (for example: basic user info, images, more user details and other details) and now I want to create store method but there is one problem my controller will be so long, I thought about using events but Im not sure if thats correct approach I would love every advice thank you in advance.

Comment: So the problem you have is that you're worried your controller will be very long because you have 33 fields split among 4 models? What does your current controller look like? This doesn't seem to have an actual problem here more of a theoretical one

Comment: Right now my contoller isn't that long but If I add 33 fields in it it will be too long right? so Im trying to find better way to create models and make controller smaller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a repository with a spearate methods that will store different parts of user data, and in case all of 33 fields are in user table, you could do it like this:

```
DB::beginTransaction();

try {
    $userId = $this->userRepository->store($request);
    $this->userRepository->storeImages($request, $userId);
    $this->userRepository->storeOtherDetails($request, $userId);

    DB::commit();
    // all good
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
}
```

I've wrapped all of this in transaction, so in case on thing fails, the others won't get stored.

storeImage and storeOtherDetails would then find the user and actually update those fields, so you could name those methods as updateUserImage or setUserImage.

If you have separate table for user images, with the matching model, you could create UserImageRepository and follow the same pattern.

Other option would be to create a static store method in the model, like so:

```
public static function createFromRequest($request)
    {
        self::create([])
    }
```

but then the model itself would be messy.

Comment: thanks for answering I will try this approach

Comment: You can thank by upvoting or marking it as a correct answer...